# Get /collection/id in backbone without loading the entire collection

Tags: collections, model, backbone.js

Is there a way to load a single entity of a Backbone collection (from the server)?

```
Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/rest/product'
});
```

The following code can load the entire collection with a `collection.fetch()` but how to load a single model? [Backbone's documentation](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync) says clearly that `GET` can be done `/collection[/id]` but not how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While we set

```
url:"api/user"
```

for the collection, the equivalent for the model is

```
urlRoot:"api/user"
```

this will make backbone automatically append the /id when you fetch()

Answer (score 9):

The model has to be declared that way:

```
Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: function() {
    return '/rest/product/'+this.id;
  }
});
```

Using it is simple as:

```
var model = new ProductModel();
model.id = productId;
model.fetch({ success: function(data) { alert(JSON.stringify(data))}});
```

Comment: Are you sure it's ok to use `model.id = productId` instead of `model.set('id', productId)`?

Comment: Yep, sure. The model uses this.id which is not a backbone attributes. Using model.set('id', ..) requires to use model.get('id') in his proper class. Both works, mine won't interfere with the backbone model attributes :D

Answer (score 4):

`collection.fetch( {data: { id:56 } } )`

Comment: Works as expected +1. But it gives me error after the execution of above line. `Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function `. Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
Catalog.Categories.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
fetchOne : function (id, success) {
    var result = this.get(id);
    if (typeof result !== 'undefined') {
        console.log(result, 'result')
        success.apply(result);
        return;
    }
    var where = {};
    where[this.model.prototype.idAttribute] = id;
    var model = new this.model(where);
    this.add(model);
    console.log(this._idAttr, where, this.model)
    model.fetch({success: function () {
        success.apply(model);
    }});
}
};
```

Now call it:

```
collection.fetchOne(id, function () {console.log(this)});
```

No more guessing if the model is already in the collection!. However, you have to use a call back as you can't depend on an intimidate result. You could use async false to get around this limitation.

Comment: This works better and can easily be added to Backbone's collection prototype

Answer (score 0):

just [`.fetch`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-fetch) a Model.

So create a model with it's own `.url` function.

Something like

```
function url() {
  return "/test/product/" + this.id;
}
```

Comment: The following code does not work: 
`url: '/rest/product/'+this.id`

Comment: @yvesamsellem after reading more carefully, `.url` needs to be a function

Comment: @Raynos thanks. Is there a way to not repeat the url in the model and the collection?

Comment: @yvesamsellem The only way I can think is to extend the collection. With lazy loading functionality

Comment: @Raynos can you please complete your answer with a sample of code?

Comment: @yvesamsellem That's not simple functionality to implement. I might have a go at it later.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var Products = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Product,
  url: '/rest/product'
});
var products = new Products();
var first = new Product({id:1});
first.collection = products;
first.fetch();
```

This has the advantage of working when you're not using a REST storage engine (instead, using something like the HTML5 Local storage, or so forth)