# How to call fetch method of Backbone Collection passing Id

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

I want to fire `fetch` method on Backbone Collection which would pass an Id parameter similar to what happens in `Model.fetch(id)`

E.g.

```
var someFoo= new Foo({id: '1234'});// Where Foo is a Backbone Model
someFoo.fetch();
```

My Backbone collection:-

```
var tasks = backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: taskModel,
    url: '/MyController/GetTasks',
    initialize: function () {
        return this;
    }
});
```

In my View when I try to fetch data:-

```
var _dummyId = 10; //

// Tried approach 1 && It calls an api without any `id` parameter, so I get 500 (Internal Server Error).
this.collection.fetch(_dummyId); 


// Tried approach 2 && which fires API call passing Id, but just after that 
// I am getting error as below:- Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
this.collection.fetch({
    data: {
        id: _dummyId
    }
});
```

Found it very late : To cut short the above story I want something like [**Get /collection/id in backbone**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262444/get-collection-id-in-backbone-without-loading-the-entire-collection).

Comment: Why are you trying to fetch a single model's data by calling `fetch()` on a collection? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: Assuming I have `Department Details` (Backbone Model), which has `List<task>`, not I need to fire a `GetTask` api, which will have `department id` as parameter and return `List<task>` wrt DepartmentId.. I may be not that clear with the question.. Apology for that!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, finally I got the solution from [Backbone.js collection options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464417/backbone-js-collection-options).

Apologies that I couldn't explain the question properly while for same requirement others have done brilliantly and smartly.

Solution : I can have something like :-

```
var Messages = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  initialize: function(models, options) {
    this.id = options.id;
  },
  url: function() {
    return '/messages/' + this.id;
  },
  model: Message,
});

var collection = new Messages([], { id: 2 });
collection.fetch();
```

Thanks to `nrabinowitz`. [Link to the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8465721/769678)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Matt Ball, the question doesn't make sense: either you call fetch() on a Collection to retrieve all the Models from the Server, or you call fetch() on a Model with an ID to retrieve only this one.

Now, if for some reason you'd need to pass extra parameters to a Collection.fetch() (such as paging information), you could always add a 'data' key in your options object, and it may happen that one of this key be an id (+add option to add this fetched model rather than replace the collection with just one model)... but that would be a very round-about way of fetching a model. The expected way is to create a new Model with the id and fetch it:

```
this.collection = new taskCollection();
newTask = this.collection.add({id: 15002});
newTask.fetch();
```

In your code however, I don't see where the ID is coming from, so I am wondering what did you expect to be in the 'ID' parameter that you wanted the collection.fetch() to send?

Comment: I'm getting an error for `this.collection.add()` Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function