# Backbone.js - should I use Model or Collection for the job?

Tags: rest, sorting, backbone.js, crud

I have limited knowledge of Backbone.js and I am having some troubles in applying the concepts of `Model` and `Collections` for the project.

On the server/database side, it is designed that: users can CRUD a list of `Category`'s which is like a Backbone.js's `Collection`s. Under `Category`, users can CRUD `Worksheet`s. Under `Worksheet`, users can CRUD `Item`s.

Should I have `Worksheet` as a `Collection` or a `Model`? Or can I have a `Collection` of `Items` inside a `Model` of `Worksheet`? If so, how can I do that?

Also, apart from the usual CRUD RESTful operations, what is the best way to implement ordering/sorting of `Model`s within a `Collection` using Backbone.js with REST? I want the `Item`s to be able for users to sort within the `Worksheet`. I've read a few Backbone.js tutorials, they mostly cover the CRUD operations and not something else like sorting.

May be I have missed something but I just don't understand the point of `Collection`, there is a `fetch` method under `Collection` but can I fetch all `Model`s under one particular `Collection` using a collection id?  Tutorials don't cover something like this....

Comment: Backbone doesn't support nested structures out of the box, you might want to look into something like http://backbonerelational.org/#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind, the point of using the model/collection classes are to take advantage of their methods, vs creating a simple array.
So with event handling for example, you can listen to events on a single model, OR you can listen to an entire collection of models. And then update the server as needed.

If you have multiple worksheets, then worksheets can be a new collection as well. Which means each worksheet will be a backbone model.

Sorting a collection:

1. See collection methods in docs, especially [underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods)
2. You can add sorting methods to the collection by extending the Backbone Collection class, and then creating a new instance. example:

   ```
   var SortableCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       sortThis: function() {
           // return 'this' sorted
       }
   });
   var collection = new SortableCollection();
   SortableCollection.sortThis();
   ```

Regarding fetching a collection, [this answer may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20305882/how-to-call-fetch-method-of-backbone-collection-passing-id)

Comment: Sorry, may be I didn't explain it well. I meant to actually sort the Items on the database via REST, not just for the sake of displaying sorted items with JS.